# User Interface Privilege Isolation in XP SP3

Tags: c++, security, winapi, windows-xp, uipi

Just after a bit of confirmation really:

Does XP SP3 implement the User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI) mechanism found in Vista?

Back story for human interest :)
I've recently been handed the C++ source to a fairly large application. Sadly the sole developer of this application, since its inception back in the mid 90's, passed away recently leaving us in a pretty tight spot until we can hire a new developer.

Recently users have reported that the application has randomly stopped working and/or certain features that previously worked don't seem to fire at all "although nothing has changed my end!". The "nothing changed" turned out to be SP3 :)

Knowing this, and although I'm not a C/C++ guy, I thought I'd take a look at the source to see if I could find out anything (having spent a great deal of time looking at firewalls, virus scanners and other external factors).

I traced one error to a call to an Api function, SendMessage, and went to the MSDN docs to take a look. It clearly states **"Microsoft Windows Vista and later. Message sending is subject to User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI). The thread of a process can send messages only to message queues of threads in processes of lesser or equal integrity level."** Whilst I'm not 100% sure, this does seem to be a probable cause.

Cheers!

Lenny.

Answer (score 4):

No, XP SP3 doesn't implement any of the Vista security changes, at least not any related to the window manager. You don't really give much background to help, but what sort of error do you get that's associated with SendMessage()?

SendMessage() is a very widely used routine that simply dispatches a Windows message to a window, so I'd expect that the error is associated with how the recipient window handles the incoming message (or not) rather than with SendMessage() itself. Rather than thinking of SendMessage() as being just a Windows function, you've got to think of it as a function that will end up calling further application code in whatever application owns the window that you sent the message to - in particular, the return code from SendMessage() tells you how the window's application got on trying to process the message.

Answer (score 0):

UIPI doesn't report errors on SendMessage - if you're getting an error returned, then it's something else. And the other commenters are right, UIPI is on Vista only, and you wouldn't get bit by this *anyways* unless you were trying to send a message to a service, for example.